# React component DOM not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects. Each object represents a product and they are added and removed from this array and the DOM reflects this properly. Problem is when I update one of the properties of these objects the DOM doesn't reflect this update.

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'

var stack = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState() {
    return {order: []};
  },
  AddToOrder(amount, product) {

    var order = this.state.order, isInOrder = false;

    order.map((object, i) => {
      if (object.productId === product.productId) {
        object.amount = product.amount + amount;  //This change doesn't show
        isInOrder = true;
      }
      return;
    })


    if (!isInOrder)  {
      product.amount = amount;
      order.push(product);        //This change is updated
    } 

    this.setState({order: order});

  },
  render() {
    return (
        <table>
          {<OrderRow products={this.state.order}/>}
        </table>    
      )
    }
})

class OrderRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <tbody>
        {this.props.products.map((object, i) => {
            return  <tr key={i}>
                <td> {object.name}</td>
                <td> 
                  <input     
                    type='number' defaultValue={object.amount} /> //This doesn't update in DOM when I change the products amount in stack component
                </td>

                </tr>;
              })}
          </tbody>
        );
      }
    }

export default stack;
```

In this example the "ChangeName" functions changes however are reflected in the DOM. Why is this?

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'

var stack = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState() {
    return {order: []};
  },
  AddToOrder(amount, product) {

    var order = this.state.order;

    var isInOrder = false;

    order.map((object, i) => {
      if (order[i].productId === product.productId) {
        order[i].amount = product.amount + amount;  //This change doesn't show
        isInOrder = true;
      }
      return;
    })


    if (!isInOrder)  {
      product.amount = amount;
      order.push(product);        //This change is updated
    } 

    this.setState({order: order});
    return;

  },
  changeName() {
    var order = this.state.order;
    order[0].name = "name changed"; //Make sure there is one object in order
    this.setState({order: order});

  },
  render() {
    return (
        <table>
          {<OrderRow products={this.state.order}/>}
        </table>    
      )
    }
})

class OrderRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <tbody>
        {this.props.products.map((object, i) => {
            return  <tr key={i}>
                <td> {object.name}</td>
                <td> 
                  <input     
                    type='number' defaultValue={object.amount} /> 
                </td>
            </tr>;
          })}
      </tbody>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [forceUpdate()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) for this.

Comment: Hey, Even though I used forceupdate in the end of AddToOrder function it doesn't update the defaultValue of the input.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
AddToOrder(amount, product) {

    var order = this.state.order, isInOrder=false;

    for(let i in order){
        if(order[i].productId === product.productId){       
            order[i].amount = product.amount + amount;
            isInOrder = true;
            break; // break it if table contains unique entries
        }
    }

    if (!isInOrder)  {
      product.amount = amount;
      order.push(product);      
    } 

    this.setState({order: order});
    return;
}
```

Comment: Hey, unfortunately not. It seems like the same thing written a little differently?

Answer (score 0):

Use `value` instead of `defaultValue` in input div.

```
<input type='number' defaultValue={object.amount} />
```

Should be

```
<input type='number' value={object.amount} />
```

If someone knows why this is, please edit or make a separate answer.

Comment: Adding onChange function to my input field and in the function giving the prop a new value fixed the editing problem. More instructions here: https://www.peterbe.com/plog/onchange-in-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are using class component inside render you should use the orderRow as a function and call it inside the render function as {orderRow();}

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33417564)